# Vim line replace that contains word

Tags: vim, replace, utf-8, line, encode

I have a text that its wrong encoded, I need to replace all the lines where:

"<96>   DASH    <96>" appears

And change that line to "-  DASH    -"

```
<96>    DASH    <96>
¡Bah    NC  unknown
!   FS  !
<96>    DASH    <96>
exclamó VLfin   exclamar
Olaf    NP  unknown
<96>    DASH    <96>
.   FS  .
Ahora   ADV ahora
```

The three elements must be separated by tabs and a CR at the end

```
-   DASH    -
¡Bah    NC  unknown
!   FS  !
-   DASH    -
exclamó VLfin   exclamar
Olaf    NP  unknown
-   DASH    -
.   FS  .
Ahora   ADV ahora
```

Any advice?

Comment: does `%s/<96>/-/g` help?

Comment: not because the <96> its a code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
:%s/\%x96\s*DASH\s*\%x96/-\tDASH\t-/
```

The most important thing above is that `\%x..` lets you search for an hexadecimal char code. The rest of the command may be modified to better fit your needs.

See `:h /\%x`

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this:

```
:%s/<96>\tDASH\t<96>\n/-\tDASH\t-\r/g
```